# I have a project that ask me to create button,and user enter the radius and location of the circle, then user click button to draw the circle

Tags: java, swing

This program is asking the user to input the data of a circle.  The following are included: the position of x, position of y, and the width and height of the circle.

So when I test this program, I enter the location and its size; and then I hit the draw button. The circle did not appear.

Here is my code!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Draw extends JFrame
{
    private JButton draw;
    private JTextField posOfX;
    private JTextField posOfY;
    private JTextField Jwidth;
    private JTextField Jheight;
    private ActionListener listener;
    private JLabel JLx;
    private JPanel drawingPanel;
    private JLabel JLy;
    private JLabel JLwidth;
    private JLabel JLheight;
    private JComponent component;
    public int x =100 ;
    public  int y =100 ;
    public  int width = 100;
    public  int height = 100 ;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Draw()
    {
        listener  = new actionPerform();
        component = new drawCircle();
        panel = new JPanel();
        draw = new JButton ("Draw");
        draw.addActionListener(listener);
        posOfX = new JTextField( 15);
        posOfY = new JTextField(15);
        Jwidth = new JTextField(15);
        Jheight = new JTextField(15);
        JLx = new JLabel("X");
        JLy = new JLabel("Y");
        JLwidth = new JLabel("Width");
        JLheight = new JLabel("Height");
        panel.add(JLx);
        panel.add(posOfX);
        panel.add(JLy);
        panel.add(posOfY);
        panel.add(JLwidth);
        panel.add(Jwidth);
        panel.add(JLheight);
        panel.add(Jheight);
        panel.add(draw);
        panel.add(component);
        add(drawingPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    class drawCircle extends JComponent
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
        }
    }

    class actionPerform implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try{
            if(e.getSource() == draw)
            {
                width = width + Integer.parseInt(Jwidth.getText());
                height = height + Integer.parseInt(Jheight.getText());
                x = Integer.parseInt(posOfX.getText()) + width;
                y = Integer.parseInt(posOfY.getText())+ height;
                Jwidth.setText("");
                Jheight.setText("");
                posOfX.setText("");
                posOfY.setText("");
            }
            }

            catch (Exception except)
            {
                Jwidth.setText("");
                Jheight.setText("");
                posOfX.setText("");
                posOfY.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You should enter numbers only","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class DrawViewer
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Draw d = new Draw();

        d.setVisible(true);
        d.setTitle("Draw circle");
        d.setSize(1000,1000);
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn to use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new `JComponent` object without a layout manager, the width of its preferred size is initially 0 and its height 0, so it's not at all visible. To fix this, your `drawCircle` class should override the `getPreferredSize` method so that the component you add it to knows what its size should be. For example:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

It is strongly encouraged that you use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) of some sort, however, so that you won't end up with various problems such as the size of components being wrong.

Comment: You should override the `getPreferredSize()`method of the DrawCirlce class to return the size of the component based on the painting code. Only the component that does the painting knows what the real size of the component should be.

Comment: - -OH MY GOD, ITS STILL NOT WORKING. CAN YOU TELL ME HOW IT WOKRS BASE ON MY CODE ? PLEASE!!!!!

Comment: @Johnny You might try changing the values in the constructor call if it's still not visible -- try 500, 500 for example.